# Shortcode in custom theme not showing no matter what

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I made a simple WordPress theme which I'm testing locally. I got a Instagram feed plugin which gives me a shortcode to add anywhere on my blog/theme. The problem is, the shortcode does not display the feed or anything for that matter but I can see the feed's code (div) when I check the page source code. Other shortcode works but not this one. The Instagram feed works on other themes but not mine. I've tried almost all the online solutions (add_filter, do_shortcode etc) but none works.

I'm sure the problem is not in the shortcode or plugin because it works on other themes and maybe there is some problem with my theme. I had also made a WordPress theme before and the feed doesn't work even in that. I don't what code to show because I really don't the where the problem is in my theme. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

The shortcode is **[instashow id="2"]**
I've tried adding that to a page but that doesn't work. I've also tried adding `<?php echo do_shortcode('[instashow id="2"]'); ?>` in the template itself but that doesn't work either.

Comment: any error are there??

Comment: The feed does not appear. If you mean by other errors, then no.

Comment: what actually want to do please put code that you tried.

Comment: I need this , add_shortcode()

Comment: I don't have that in my functions.php. I just added these two that I got from some online solutions. add_filter ( 'the_excerpt' ,   'wpc_custom_excerpt' ) ; add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');

Comment: provide url i can't understand your functionality

Comment: without adding a shortcode,how could you retrieve?

Comment: I do add the actual shortcode but not the add_shortcode() because I didn't make this plugin. Anyhow, I setup a blog online for you to look at. It's another theme but feed doesn't work on this either. http://marwan.in/pages/instagram

Comment: you have to add code in functions.php and add_shortcode

Comment: Can you please help me with that. The plugin works on other themes but not mine. IDK what more to add really.

Comment: In your site any where its displayed??

Comment: The website I gave you has that shortcode both in the page content and within the page code it self. None of them are showing. Check the page source code, and search for instashow, It's showing the DIV in the source code but not showing the feed on the page.

Comment: nothing displayed here

Comment: I mean the content of div is always empty whether the feed is showing or not showing. It's the same div. The problem is that the feed itself isn't showing on the page.

Comment: I can't help without code.You are not understand what I try to deliver.

Comment: Okay this is the page.php code: http://pastebin.com/rxZmZ1Lt

Answer (score 0):

You checked to see if the plugin settings are correct?
The next step would be to check other shortcodes in other plugins to see if other shortcodes work or have problems too.

First you have to make sure if the problem is caused by the theme or the plugin.